# How to tell Xcode to automatically set image asset render mode in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In Xcode 6 you can tell any image in an assets catalog to always `Render As` `Default`, `Original Image` or `Template Image` through the Attributes inspector. Like this

[image]

But this **only** works for iOS 8, not for iOS 7.

Is there a way to do the same but working on iOS 7 as well?

*Note: I'm not looking for programmatic solutions (like those using things like* `image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];`*), but for a declarative one, either in `images.xcassets` panels or in storyboards and nibs.*

Comment: This sound like a bug to me, did you fire a bug report yet?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you set the button type to "System" (vs "Custom"), "templating" behaves as expected under iOS 7 for button images. Unfortunately, it still does not work for button background images and it does not allow using custom images for any other state than "Default".

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a solution for images themselves, not just for buttons.